# TPS54560 based bulk circuit output voltage drop off

Tags: circuit-design

I use TI's WEBENCH Power Designer designed a DC/DC bulk circuit and make a board, but when I load a 12 V@4 A pump with this board, it can work a while, and then the output voltage will drop to 8 V, and the Schottky diode is very hot(can smell and it will burn if not power off.)

I feel completely puzzled, because I make the board completely according to the TI's design nearly.

Then I use a small pump, about 12 V@1 A，it works fine, but the catch diode is also touch hot(not smell).

[image]
[Customize  TPS54560BQDDARQ1  ‑  15V-60V to 12.00V @ 5A](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=7F2C1B4AC6F96013)

the Schottky diode type is VS-50WQ10FNTRL-M3.
[image]

Schematic:
[image]

Layout:
[image]

Comment: What diode are you using? What is its current rating? What is the current rating for your inductor?

Comment: Please show your exact schematic with part numbers and your layout. Especially show where you deviated from TI according to “I make the board completely according to the TI's design _nearly_“.

Comment: OK,I have done these to my post.

Comment: What was VIN when that happened?

Comment: Keep in mind according to the design, with high input votlages and 4A output that diode will be dissipating around 3.5W. That's enough to get extremely hot if the thermal design isn't good.

Comment: Your switch loop is about 10 times the size recommended in the datasheet, page 39. You also seem to be missing a ground plane. What's the ESR of the output capacitor?

Comment: Yes,not consistent with the datasheet.The output capacitor ESR is not listed in datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Right, this circuit lost thermal design, the catch diode  was unstable when hot.

After I've read everyone's help I added a 12V small fan, stick the Schottky diode and TPS54560 chip with radiators. Just used pure mechanical methods.

It now can continuous work (12V@~3.6A).

I tested one hour more, the environmental temp. is 26 °C, the output voltage is stable at 11.73V.

Thanks for your guidance.

[image: testing pic.]